# IIS7 is gzipping files but not serving the gzipped version

Tags: iis, iis-7, gzip

By following a number of helpful blog posts I have configured IIS to gzip my static files. I have even enabled Failed Request Tracing and filtered to the 200 status code, and I can see the successful compression events taking place as well as the finished headers, which look like this:

```
Headers="Content-Type: text/css
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Mon, 04 Oct 2010 17:35:08 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "02ef37cea63cb1:0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
"
```

However, when I test in Fiddler and Firefox the **Content-Encoding** header is missing, and the file is not gzipped.

This is a similar issue to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/72069/how-can-i-troubleshoot-why-my-iis7-site-is-not-gzip-compressing) which was never resolved.

IIS is generating the gzipped files which I can see in C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files .

Does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please see my answer to this question. It may help: http://serverfault.com/questions/505788/why-is-gzip-compression-varying-in-efficiency-in-iis

Answer (score 1):

The content was being served gzipped, but my company's network was stripping out that header. When I accessed the site from home, it worked.